# Intel's IPMI tool fails in WinPE 10 64-bit

Tags: windows-10, winpe, ipmi, tcl

The IPMI app I have, Intel's [IPMI, V2.0, Command Test Tool](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/icts_v602.zip) from  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/ipmi/ipmi-technical-resources.html is rejected by WinPE 10 which states "This version is not compatible with the version you're running." How would I resolve that? I have to execute it from within WinPE 10.

Win10PE is 64-bit and used to install 64-bit Windows. The app relies on Tcl/Tk scripts.

I am also open to alternative open source apps which will run in WinPE 10.

Comment: Write your own version of the tool? If it's not compatible, there's not much you can do about it...WinPE is not meant to be a full OS replacement, hence the name Preinstallation Environment

Comment: If I am not mistaken WinPE is 32-bit, is the tool in question, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Pretty sure WinPE can be 64-bit as well...

Comment: WinPE might only be 64-bit.

Comment: Presumption of it being 64-bit isn’t enough.  WinPE doesn’t have Windows on Windows 64 which would be required to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit OS.  So is both the tool and WinPE or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the scripted install of 64-bit OS is in use, Win10 PE is presumed to be 64-bit. The app relies on Tcl/Tk scripts.

So "program" is simply several batch files.  The DLL files are 32-bit, so you need to use a 32-bit instance of WinPE otherwise, the application won't work.  Make sure you define the required system variables.

> How would I resolve that?

You need to use a 32-bit version of WinPE in order to run the batch files.  There might be other requirements that I am not able to determine, from the just the compress archive you linked to, but all indications are that the files will only work on a 32-bit version of Windows (WinPE included).

Comment: It might be extremely difficult to make that tool run on WinPE but I don't see any indication that it's not possible.